# Firebase: How to programmatically obtain the default realtime database URL for a project?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

We have 3 Firebase projects – one for production, one for staging and one for development.

Production and staging were created before Dec 2020 and their "project names" and database ids match: (`"project-foo"` maps to `"project-foo.firebaseio.com"` database url).

For a newly created "development" project, after I pressed "Create Database" in the dashboard, new database got a url that doesn't match the project name:
(`"project-foo-development"` maps to `"project-foo-development-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app"`).

I am writing a script that operates on all 3 environments and it’s clear that I can’t make an assumption that database url will match the project id, or that the top level domain for database hosting will be the same.

How do I obtain the *default* database URL **dynamically** from firebase so I can apply my scripting to all 3 environments?

I understand that I can obtain the url from the dashboard, but ideally I’d only need the project names, since these ids/urls seem to be controlled by Firebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I quickly tested this with the REST API, and I can get the correct value from its [`projects.getAdminSdkConfig` call](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects/getAdminSdkConfig). In the result of that call you'll find a `databaseURL` key with the full database URL as its value.